# How to find vulnerabilities in stripped binaries?

Tags: security, debugging, exploit, binaries

Do you just use tools like strace and a debugger to disassemble and find syscalls and then read the disassembly to find say for example a buffer overflow? Is that all you can do? I mean after all you don't have the source code.

If someone could shed some light on this particular topic I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: This does not seem to be a good fit for Stack Overflow even though it makes reference to symbols and disassemblies. Its broad for Stack overflow, and we usually see references to symbols and disassemblies in a different context. Perhaps [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Play CTF(Capture The Flag)

This site contain a lot of CTF events.

https://ctftime.org/

Once you learn more, you could know more technique to exploit.

Also, maybe this helps.

This repo contains write-ups which CTF player writes.

https://github.com/ctfs/write-ups-2016